# CXF: Set minOccurs=0 for elements of the arrays

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, aegis

We use CXF framework with aegis mapper for java server and .NET client.
By default we have minOccurs=0 for all variables in classes in WSDL.
We use such setting in CXF config to prevent it:

```
    <bean id="aegisBean" class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding" scope="prototype">
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.TypeCreationOptions">
            <property name="defaultNillable" value="false"/>
            <property name="defaultMinOccurs" value="1"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But we have another problem with array. For array we have such code in WSDL:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfDetails">
 <xsd:sequence> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Details" type="tns:Details"/>
 </xsd:sequence> 
 </xsd:complexType>
```

So empty arrays are not accepted:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: The number of elements in {http://dto.WebServices.com}ArrayOfDetails does not meet the mini mum of 1
```

Is it possible, to add annotation to array, which set minOccurs="0" to elements of the array (not to the whole array)? Or is it possible to set it is aegis configuration for all arrays?

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Details" type="tns:Details"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [mapping file](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/aegis-21.html#Aegis%282.1%29-DetailedControlofBeanTypeMapping):

```
 <mappings>
  <mapping name="ArrayOfDetails">
    <property name="Details" minOccurs='0'/>
  </mapping>
</mappings>
```